# Only update fields that are not null

Tags: php, mysql, null, dreamweaver

I have been trying to figure out how to update the fields only if they are not null (otherwise NULL overrides the unchanged fields). It doesn't matter that the fields can not be null.

I have tried both the COALESCE and ISNULL, however I must not be using them in the right way as I'm not use to the Dreamweaver coding. The code is below:

```
<i>if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "catalogue")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE catalogue SET catbox1=%s, catbox2=%s, catbox3=%s, catbox4=%s, catbox5=%s, catbox6=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox5'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['catbox6'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));</i>
```

Comment: I update to add the code block. To do this, select your block and click the code block button in the toolbar (it's the one the looks like `{}`)

Comment: You are using Dreamweaver. There's your first problem.

Comment: Can you show the application of your IS NULL?

Comment: I used SET catbox1=ISNULL(%s), catbox2=ISNULL(%s)...

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in you code, But these can be typos.

1. NO PHP Wrapper: You have include your mysqlcode with  portion
2. Use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `ISNULL`

Basic way of what you are trying to do is use a query like this

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `fieldName` = 'value' WHERE `fieldName` IS NOT NULL
```