# Update Mysql except when field not null

Tags: php, mysql

I am rephrasing my question.

I'd like to write a single query to bypass the update of a field when that field it is not null.

I use the following code to update:

```
$bouton='Submit';
$recu=$_POST; $titre=""; $contenu=""; $reqComplete="";
foreach ($recu as $titre => $contenu) {
    $contenu=trim(addslashes($contenu));
    if($titre!=$bouton AND $contenu!=""){
        $reqComplete.=$titre."='$contenu', ";
    }
}
$reqComplete=rtrim($reqComplete, ", ");
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","name","password") or die("Could not connect to database");
$rs = mysql_select_db("name_immigDB",$conn) or die ("Could not select database");
$requete="UPDATE form1738 SET $reqComplete where email_address = \"$email_address\"";
$resultat=mysql_query($requete) or die ("Invalid request : <br /> ".mysql_error());
$requete="select max(idimmigDB) from form1738";
$rs= mysql_query($requete,$conn);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$_SESSION[id]=$row[0];
mysql_close($conn);
```

There should be something to change in

```
$requete="UPDATE form1738 SET $reqComplete where email_address = \"$email_address\"";
```

but cant figure out what.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, go for it

Comment: is there ("field only if it is not null, but leave it alone where it is not null") or would you like to change and leave it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only update fields that are not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097924/only-update-fields-that-are-not-null)

Comment: *Possible* duplicate? More like couldn't be bothered looking! By the way, loved the first comment.

Comment: How long is my question gonna be on hold?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IS` operator to compare with `NULL`

```
update your_table
set some_field = 'some value'
where some_field is not null
```

Using `= NULL` will not work since comparing with `null` results in *unknown* which is not `TRUE`.

Comment: I'd say I'm surprised that such a high-rep user is answering such a blatantly low-effort question, but that seems to be the norm nowadays.  I really need to accept that.